# D3 Javascript plotting function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to write a tutorial about d3 and I found couple websites that can help but with not enough details.

I have the following code that outputs a bar chart:

```
<html>
<head>
<div id="mainGraph">
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var t = 1, // start time (seconds since epoch)
    v = 0, // start value (subscribers)
    data = d3.range(33).map(next); // starting dataset

 function next() {
   return {
    time: ++t,
     value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(80, Math.exp(t)))
   };
}
setInterval(function() {
   data.shift();
   data.push(next());
 }, 1500);

  var w = 40,
      h = 100;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, w]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
     .rangeRound([0, h]);

     var chart = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg:svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", w * data.length + 10)
     .attr("height", h);

     chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) + 5; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) + 5; })
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

     chart.append("svg:line")
     .attr("x1", 0)
     .attr("x2", w * data.length)
     .attr("y1", h + 5)
     .attr("y2", h + 5)
     .attr("stroke", "#000");





    </script>           
    </body>
    </html>
```

The first question is what does function()

the second question is when I try to change the set of data so i am trying to put v in function of t like v = Math.exp (t)
this is not working and its giving me a black line only even though I changed the interval of max and min.
Thank you.

Comment: Answered your first question, can you setup a jsfiddle example for your second question?

Comment: @DominicGoulet this is the example I am trying to plot the function using this code. Probably I didn't get what you meant about  setup a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net and setup the example that don't work for you. Then, post the jsfiddle link here so we can fork your code and make it work.

Comment: ok this is the link for the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/akabalan/ds4Wa/

Comment: Okay, I made a clear example out of yours, what is not working exactly? I see a black band bar chart... http://jsfiddle.net/pF858/

Comment: @DominicGoulet what is not working is the graph itself it stops plotting the exponential function after a while I tried to change the interval of both the variables and chart but it is not working.

Comment: Got it! The problem is `~~Math.max(10, Math.min(80, Math.exp(t)))`. It stops at 80 because you basically tell it to do so. Math.min will get the minimum value between 80 and Math.exp, and when the exp will be greater than 80 then you will cap at 80. You might want to change it to `~~Math.max(10, Math.exp(t))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function()` as in :

```
setInterval(function() { ... });
```

is called a lambda function (or anonymus if you prefer). This means that the function has no name, and cannot be called outside it's scope. In this case, the `setInterval`  function requires a function as parameter, so we send in the full function definition instead of just a reference to it.